# Eclipse not recognizing Java 8 libaries

Tags: java, eclipse

Oracle Java 8 introduced LocalDateTime, LocalDate, LocalTime, among other classes. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and so I use Eclipse Indigo, which is available through the software center. I have Oracle Java 8 set as my default:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status

------------------------------------------------------------

* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1062      auto mode

  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode

  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode

  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1062      manual mode


$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_05"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)


$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_05
```

In Eclipse, Project > Properties > Java Build path, it is using JRE System Library [java-8-oracle].

Yet Eclipse cannot resolve any of these imports:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: did you install the update for java 8 for eclipse http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

Comment: @JigarJoshi I am using Eclipse Indigo, since that is what is available in Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: does it understand java 8, can you see 1.8 under preferences > java > compiler > compiler compliance level

Comment: @JigarJoshi the compiler compliance level only goes up to 1.7. It doesn't have a 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jigar stated in the comments, you need to install the [Java 8 support plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) to enable 1.8 as a compliance level. Alternatively, just grab the latest [Luna release candidate](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?osType=linux&release=undefined) which has Java 8 support built-in.

Comment: This is going to work in Eclipse Indigo? On Ubuntu Software Center, the newest version of Eclipse is Indigo.

Comment: Ubuntu is pretty conservative with what they include in their repositories. At this point Indigo is 3 major releases behind. I would grab a later version from Eclipse.org.

Comment: Well I installed Eclipse Kepler and the errors went away. Unfortunately now that I am using Kepler, I cannot take advantage of the Software Center's automatic updates.

Comment: I'll reiterate that Indigo is *3* major versions behind -- so the "automatic updates" don't appear to be buying Ubuntu users anything as it is. :P